# UITableView does not display cell immediately after reloading data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In viewDidload, tableview load data from server

```
success:^(NSArray *array) {
    if (!_dataSource) {
        _dataSource = [@[] mutableCopy];
    }
    if (array) {
        [_dataSource addObjectsFromArray:array];
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

then every time I pull up from bottom, get new data from server and appended it to the **_dataSource**(the same way like first time)

```
success:^(NSArray *array) {
    if (!_dataSource) {
        _dataSource = [@[] mutableCopy];
    }
    if (array) {
        [_dataSource addObjectsFromArray:array];
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

now the problem is coming: sometime pull up from bottom, and **get new data successly,but the tableview does not display new cell immediately,when I sweep the tableview a bit(even just touch the screen) the new cell displayed**.
 What problem it could be?

### Edit

Because every cell is not the same height, so I do not *reuse* cell, and init a new cell every time,is this reason?

```
//    TopicCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TopicCellIdentifier];
//    if(!cell){    
//        cell = [[TopicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TopicCellIdentifier];
//    }
TopicCell *cell = [[TopicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:TopicCellIdentifier];
```

@Jeffery Thomas, **success** is just a **AFNetworking block** like this

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
 [manager GET:path
          parameters:parameters
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation1, id responseObject) {

             }
             failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation2, NSError *error) {

             }];
```

Comment: You reloadData in mainThread?

Comment: @nmh of course `[_tableView reloadData];` is in main thread.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a bit more context. What is the method which contains `success:`?

Comment: @JefferyThomas thanks, please have a look at appended message.

Comment: What is the context of your AFNetworking call? `scrollViewDidScroll:`?

Comment: @Neil No, pull up from bottom, just like touch a button to refresh new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first guess, I would make sure you run `-reloadData` on the main thread (queue). This is pretty simple.

```
success:^(NSArray *array) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!_dataSource) {
            _dataSource = [@[] mutableCopy];
        }
        if (array) {
            [_dataSource addObjectsFromArray:array];
            [_tableView reloadData];
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set your _dataSource as block variable since you are updating your instance variable inside block? Also make sure you are reloading the data in the main thread.

Edited

Did you do something like

```
    __block YourViewController *this = self;

//Inside block
    if (!this.dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = [@[] mutableCopy];
    }
    if (array) {
        [this.dataSource addObjectsFromArray:array];
        [this.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I changed it to __block, problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake:

I made wrong page info for *_dataSorce*, for example
first time load 20 NSObjects from server, `_dataSource is [0:19]`
the second time load 20 more NSObjects from server, `_dataSource should be [0:39]`, by my mistake made it `[20:59]`
Anyway it would not show this wired issue if index of `_dataSource` is correct.